# How to implement setSyncProvider and verify it is working with PC

Tags: arduino-uno, time

I'm trying to retrieve / synchronize time from PC using this Time lib function:

```
setSyncProvider( requestSync);  //set function to call when sync required
```

It sends ASCII BEL (07) character to PC, but I'm getting no response using `Serial.available`. What am I missing?

Do I have to run a specific app on the PC to get a response? The docs do not specify that.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you'll need something running on the PC which is monitoring the serial port, and which will provide a response in the appropriate format.

The download on **[this page](http://playground.arduino.cc/code/time)** contains a Processing sketch which will do this for you. After you've unzipped it, look in `Time/Examples/Processing/SyncArduinoClock`. Open the sketch in Processing, run it, and then start your Arduino.

If you're not familiar with it, Processing is a free programming language / environment based on Java. It's aimed largely at beginners and non-programmers, and is quite commonly used for communicating with Arduino projects via Serial. You can download it here:

- http://www.processing.org